# crystal reports grand total showing on both sides of data

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm relatively new to CR.  I've created a crosstab report and the grans totals are showing on both sides of the grid on the right side it is labeled as Total and on the left there is no heading.  I want to keep the total on the right and hide or suppress the values on the right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Version of crystal reports is 2013 support pack 7  version 14.1.7.1853

[crosstab report with grand totals on both sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVbU5.png)

Answer (score 0):

never mind  - not an issue - as total noob  to CR my selection parameters was creating the issue  - not really an issue